# How to hide error bar lines behind boxplots with transparant colour?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

So ive made some boxplots where I want to have a gradual decrease in colour transparancy by adding 40 (40%) and 80 (80%) behind the fill colour codes.

However Im using stat_boxplot to have nice whiskers where the vertical lines are also visible now behind the box from the boplot....how do I hide them?

Create example df (fyi not same data as the example image):

```
df <- data.frame(Sygmoid = c(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 3, 6, 5, 9, 5, 8, 5, 4, 4, 4 ,5, 6, 6, 4 ,4 ,5),
                 setup = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7))
```

Code:

```
lines <- c("#ff0166", "#117f80", "#117f80","#117f80", "#40007f", "#40007f","#40007f")

Sygboxplot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = setup, y = Sygmoid, fill = setup)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom="errorbar", position=pd, width=0.2, lwd=0.75, colour = lines) +
  labs(x = "", y = "Distance (mm)") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#FFFFFF", "#FFFFFF", "#117f8040","#117f8080", "#FFFFFF", "#40007f40","#40007f80")) 

Sygboxplot <- Sygboxplot + geom_boxplot(notch=F, lwd=0.75, fatten = 0.6, position=pd, colour = lines) +
  ggtitle("Sigmoid width") +
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisonsSyg[4:6], label.y = c(7, 7.5, 8), label = "p.signif", method = "t.test", paired = T) +
  theme_bw(base_rect_size = 0.2) + 
  ylim(0, 8) 

#Graphpad theme
Sygboxplot <- Sygboxplot + theme_prism(base_size = 14) + theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This could be achieved by adding a second `geom_boxplot` with a white `color` and `fill` to cover the part of the errorbars inside the box:

```r
library(ggpubr)

lines <- c("#ff0166", "#117f80", "#117f80", "#117f80", "#40007f", "#40007f", "#40007f")

pd <- position_dodge()

Sygboxplot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = setup, y = Sygmoid, fill = factor(setup))) +
  stat_boxplot(aes(color = factor(setup)),
    geom = "errorbar",
    position = pd, width = 0.2, lwd = 0.75,
  ) +
  labs(x = "", y = "Distance (mm)") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#FFFFFF", "#FFFFFF", "#117f8040", "#117f8080", "#FFFFFF", "#40007f40", "#40007f80")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = lines)

Sygboxplot <- Sygboxplot +
  geom_boxplot(aes(group = factor(setup)), notch = F, fatten = NA,
               position = pd, colour = "white", fill = "white", 
               outlier.colour = NA) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(color = factor(setup)),
    notch = F, lwd = 0.75, fatten = 0.6,
    position = pd, colour = lines
  ) +
  ggtitle("Sigmoid width") +
  # stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisonsSyg[4:6], label.y = c(7, 7.5, 8), label = "p.signif", method = "t.test", paired = T) +
  theme_bw(base_rect_size = 0.2) +
  ylim(0, 8)

# Graphpad theme
Sygboxplot +
  # theme_prism(base_size = 14) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]